# webXR image tracking: Drag and Drop in AR with ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, webxr

I am literally stucked.
I am using `ThreeJS` with `image-tracking` from `webXR`.
I am trying to integrate drag and drop example of ThreeJS in order to obtain a 3D model over a qrcode having the possibilty to move around the 3D model with touch screen. The 3D model is shown over the qrcode but when I touch over the 3D model the intersection array is empty.

This is the script I did so far:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { ARButton } from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/ARButton.js';
import { GLTFLoader}  from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { XRControllerModelFactory } from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/XRControllerModelFactory';

let camera, canvas, scene, renderer;
let mesh, mesh2;
let modelsPath = ['./backpack.glb', './scissors.glb'];
let controller1, controller2;
let controllerGrip1, controllerGrip2;
let raycaster;
let tracked = false;

const intersected = [];
const tempMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

let controls, group;

setupMobileDebug()

function setupMobileDebug() {
  // for image tracking we need a mobile debug console as it only works on android
  // This library is very big so only use it while debugging - just comment it out when your app is done
  const containerEl = document.getElementById("console-ui");
  eruda.init({
    container: containerEl
  });
  const devToolEl = containerEl.shadowRoot.querySelector('.eruda-dev-tools');
  devToolEl.style.height = '40%'; // control the height of the dev tool panel
}

function onSelectStart( event ) {
  const controller = event.target;
  const intersections = getIntersections( controller );
  console.error('intersection on select start:', intersections)
  if ( intersections.length > 0 ) {
    const intersection = intersections[ 0 ];
    const object = intersection.object;
    object.material.emissive.b = 1;
    controller.attach( object );
    controller.userData.selected = object;
  }
  debugger;
  controller.userData.targetRayMode = event.data.targetRayMode;
}

function onSelectEnd( event ) {
  const controller = event.target;
  if ( controller.userData.selected !== undefined ) {
    const intersections = getIntersections( controller );
    if(intersections.length > 0){
      console.log('drop with intersection')
    }
    const object = controller.userData.selected;
    object.material.emissive.b = 0;
    group.attach( object );
    controller.userData.selected = undefined;
  }
}

function getIntersections( controller ) {
  controller.updateMatrixWorld();
  tempMatrix.identity().extractRotation( controller.matrixWorld );
  raycaster.ray.origin.setFromMatrixPosition( controller.matrixWorld );
  raycaster.ray.direction.set( 0, 0, - 1 ).applyMatrix4( tempMatrix );
  return raycaster.intersectObjects( group.children, false );
}

function intersectObjects( controller ) {
  if ( controller.userData.selected !== undefined ) return;
  const line = controller.getObjectByName( 'line' );
  const intersections = getIntersections( controller );
  if ( intersections.length > 0 ) {
    const intersection = intersections[ 0 ];
    const object = intersection.object;
    intersected.push( object );
    line.scale.z = intersection.distance;
  } else {
    line.scale.z = 5;
  }
}

function cleanIntersected() {
  while ( intersected.length ) {
    const object = intersected.pop();
    object.material.emissive.r = 0;
  }
}

init();
animate();

async function init() {
  canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.01,
    40
  );

  controls = new OrbitControls( camera, canvas );
  controls.target.set( 0, 1.6, 0 );
  controls.update();

  group = new THREE.Group();
    scene.add( group );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  renderer.xr.enabled = true;

  const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xbbbbff, 1);
  light.position.set(0.5, 1, 0.25);
  scene.add(light);

  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
      modelsPath[0],
      (gltf) => {
        mesh = gltf.scene;
        mesh.visible = false;
        mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        //mesh.scale.set(new THREE.Vector3( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ));
        scene.add(mesh);
        group.add(mesh)
      }, 
    );
    // loader.load(
    //   modelsPath[1],
    //   (gltf) => {
    //    mesh2 = gltf.scene;
    //    mesh2.visible = false;
    //    mesh2.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    //    //mesh2.scale.set(new THREE.Vector3( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 ));
    //    scene.add(mesh2);
    //    group.add(mesh2);
    //   }, 
    // );

    for ( let i = 0; i < 3; i ++ ) {
      const obj = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, ).translate( 0, 0.1, 0 );
      const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff * Math.random() } )
      const model = new THREE.Mesh( obj, material );
      model.position.x = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
      model.position.y = Math.random() * 2;
      model.position.z = Math.random() * 4 - 2;

      model.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
      model.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
      model.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

      model.scale.setScalar( Math.random() + 0.5 );

      model.castShadow = true;
      model.receiveShadow = true;
      model.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
      console.log("model", model.position);
      //group.add(model)
    }

  // setup the image targets
  const img = document.getElementById('img');
  const imgBitmap = await createImageBitmap(img);

  const qr = document.getElementById('qr');
  const qrBitmap = await createImageBitmap(qr);

  //more on image-tracking feature: https://github.com/immersive-web/marker-tracking/blob/main/explainer.md
  const button = ARButton.createButton(renderer, {
    requiredFeatures: ["image-tracking"], // notice a new required feature
    trackedImages: [
      {
        image: imgBitmap, // tell webxr this is the image target we want to track
        widthInMeters: 0.5// in meters what the size of the PRINTED image in the real world
      },
      {
        image: qrBitmap, // tell webxr this is the image target we want to track
        widthInMeters: 1.5 // in meters what the size of the PRINTED image in the real world
      }
    ],
    //this is for the mobile debug
    optionalFeatures: ["dom-overlay", "dom-overlay-for-handheld-ar"],
    domOverlay: {
      root: document.body
    }
  });
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  // controllers
  controller1 = renderer.xr.getController(0);
  controller1.addEventListener( 'selectstart', onSelectStart );
  controller1.addEventListener( 'selectend', onSelectEnd );
  scene.add( controller1 );
  
  controller2 = renderer.xr.getController(1);
  controller2.addEventListener( 'selectstart', onSelectStart );
  controller2.addEventListener( 'selectend', onSelectEnd );
  scene.add( controller2 );

  const controllerModelFactory = new XRControllerModelFactory();

  controllerGrip1 = renderer.xr.getControllerGrip(0);
  controllerGrip1.add( controllerModelFactory.createControllerModel( controllerGrip1 ) );
  scene.add(controllerGrip1);
 
  controllerGrip2 = renderer.xr.getControllerGrip(1);
  controllerGrip2.add( controllerModelFactory.createControllerModel( controllerGrip2 ) );
  scene.add(controllerGrip2);

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( [ new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ), new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 1 ) ] );

  const line = new THREE.Line( geometry );
  line.name = 'line';
  line.scale.z = 5;

  controller1.add( line.clone() );
  controller2.add( line.clone() );

  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
}

function animate() {
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(render);
}

function render(timestamp, frame) {
  // console.log(mesh, mesh2);
  cleanIntersected();

  intersectObjects(controller1);
  intersectObjects(controller2);
 
  if (frame) {
    const results = frame.getImageTrackingResults(); //checking if there are any images we track

    //if we have more than one image the results are an array 
    for (const result of results) {
      // The result's index is the image's position in the trackedImages array specified at session creation
      const imageIndex = result.index;

      // Get the pose of the image relative to a reference space.
      const referenceSpace = renderer.xr.getReferenceSpace();
      const pose = frame.getPose(result.imageSpace, referenceSpace);

      //checking the state of the tracking
      const state = result.trackingState;
      //console.log(state);

      if (state == "tracked") {
         // update the mesh when the image target is found
        if(imageIndex === 0){
          if(!tracked){
            // tracked = true;
            mesh.visible = true;
            mesh.matrix.fromArray(pose.transform.matrix);
            console.log("position: ", mesh.position);
            setTimeout(()=> tracked= true, 500 )
          }
        } else {
            mesh2.visible = true;
            mesh2.matrix.fromArray(pose.transform.matrix);
        }
      } else if (state == "emulated") {
        if(imageIndex === 0) {
          mesh.visible = false;
        }else{
          mesh2.visible = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Do you have any idea about what is wrong?

Comment: I am trying to figure out if it is a problem of positioning between raycasting and 3d model